# Memoir class - bibliography environment reference to wrong bibunit

Tags: bibliographies, memoir, bibunits

I am writing my thesis using the memoir class.

I have a main which calls all the needed files.

One of these files is the "summary" which calls two different tex files with respective bibliographies (I need to have the summary in two languages, English and Danish).

The problem is that the second bibliography (danish) doesn't show up (the references are placed perfectly but they cross-reference to the bibliography environment of the English summary).

**EDIT**: it seems that the danish summary keeps looking at the english bib file. The references are placed only if they have been cited in the english summary and they won't show up otherwise. If the reference key differ between the two bib files (e.g. test1 and test1d in the example below), the reference will not be placed properly.

Attached the MWE

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt,authoryear,longnamesfirst]{memoir}

\begin{filecontents}{englishsummary.bib}
@Article{test1,
  author =   {Test Testesen},
  title =    {Test},
  journal =      {Test journal},
  year =     {2018},
}
@Article{test2,
  author =   {Test T. Test},
  title =    {TestB},
  journal =      {Journal of testing},
  year =     {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{danishsummary.bib}

@Article{test1d,
  author =   {Test Testesen},
  title =    {Test},
  journal =      {Test journal},
  year =     {2018},
}
@Article{test2d,
  author =   {Test T. Test},
  title =    {TestB},
  journal =      {Journal of testing},
  year =     {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}

% preamble
\let\newfloat\undefined
\usepackage[capbesideposition={top,center},capposition=top]{floatrow}

\usepackage[scaled=0.75]{beramono}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,danish]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{bibunits}
\usepackage[authoryear,sectionbib,longnamesfirst]{natbib}

\setlrmarginsandblock{*}{1.228571in}{0.75} 
\setulmarginsandblock{1in}{*}{1.2}

\nouppercaseheads
\makeoddhead{headings}{\small\scshape\rightmark}{}{\small\thepage} 
\makeevenhead{headings}{\small\thepage}{}{\small\scshape\leftmark}

\linespread{1.1}

\usepackage{cleveref}
% END PREAMBLE

\begin{document}

    \selectlanguage{english}
    \frenchspacing
    \tableofcontents*
    %SUMMARY
    \let\oldbibsection\bibsection
    \let\oldbibsection\bibsection
    \renewcommand\bibsection{\section*{\bibname}}

    % English summary
    \begin{bibunit}[elsarticle-harv]
        \chapter*[Summary]{Summary}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary}

        some english text \citep{test1} and \cite{test2}.
        %\clearpage
        \putbib[englishsummary.bib]
    \end{bibunit}
    % END OF English SUMMARY

    % Danish summary
    \begin{bibunit}[elsarticle-harv_danish]
        \chapter*[Danish summary]{Danish summary}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Danish summary}
        \selectlanguage{Danish}
        \frenchspacing
        \setcounter{footnote}{0}
        %DANISH SUMMARY     
        some danish text \citep{test1d} and \cite{test2d}.
        \clearpage
        \putbib[danishsummary.bib]
    \end{bibunit}
        % END OF DANISH SUMMARY
    \selectlanguage{english}
    \frenchspacing
    \let\bibsection\oldbibsection
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE (from `\documentclass` through `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}`) that shows the error so that we can process it and try to help. For instance you use the `memoir` class but also the `bibunit` environment which is not supplied by `memoir`; where does it come from?

Comment: @PeterWilson Hi, I added the preamble. Let me know if anything else is needed. The log doesn't return any error as the references appear correctly, the fact that the bibliography environment is missing doesn't seem to be recognized as a problem

Comment: Could you please clean this up (a lot), there are many constructions and packages that are completely irrelevant for this question. Also where does the Danish bst file come from? You are imputing stuff we do not have access to, so please help us help you by making something that is minimal and self contained that others can test without having to add a lot of stuff.

Comment: Woul;d you please still make this into a single example instead of several sniplets. There is no need for the rest of us to replicate your folder structure. As you can see from my example below, there is no issues in making a single MWE.

Comment: @daleif, Hi, thank you very much for taking the time to show me how to properly make a MWE. I edited the question, not it's as compact as it can be while still respecting the way the whole thesis is built.
When running your sample code I have absolutely no problem, each summary properly displays the correct references and prints the proper bibliography environment

Comment: @delaif I'll see what I can do =) I'll edit the question asap. thanks again

Comment: I do not understand this sentence: ". If the reference key differ between the two bib files (e.g. test1 and test1d in the example below), the reference will not be placed properly. " Again, please make this into a single MWE, then it is A LOT easier to help you. We do not want to replicate your folder structure.

Comment: You forgot to update the two `\putbib[Frontmatter/Summaries/...]`, point it to files in the current folder (made ealier on via filecontents), and the bibtex configuration files should probably changed to something available of all, like `plainnat` (that X_danish` version you're using is not available on ctan)

Comment: @daleif I think you just found the problem. If I change the bibtex configuration file to plainnat the danish bibliography environment pops up. Now I need to figure out what's special about the file I was calling

Comment: Now you know why making the single MWE is important, and why it is important to make them self contains and only using stuff others have access to. That process often ends up revealing the issue.

Comment: @daleif thanks again, do you have any idea why it was automatically referring to the previous bibliography environment instead of returning an error?

Comment: No idea, as mentioned I do not have your files or the bst you are using, so cannot test from here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a re-edit of the OPs current MWE (20180831 12:10)

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{englishsummary.bib}
@Article{test1,
  author =   {Test Testesen},
  title =    {Test english},
  journal =      {Test journal},
  year =     {2018},
}
@Article{test2,
  author =   {Test T. Test},
  title =    {TestB english},
  journal =      {Journal of testing},
  year =     {2018},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{danishsummary.bib}
@Article{test1d,
  author =   {Test TestesenD},
  title =    {Test danish},
  journal =      {Test journal},
  year =     {2018},
}
@Article{test2d,
  author =   {Test T. TestD},
  title =    {TestB danish},
  journal =      {Journal of testing},
  year =     {2018},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish,english]{babel}

\usepackage{bibunits}
\usepackage[authoryear,sectionbib,longnamesfirst]{natbib}

\begin{document}

    \selectlanguage{english}
    \tableofcontents*


    % English summary
    \begin{bibunit}[plainnat]
        \chapter*[Summary]{Summary}

        some english text \citep{test1} and \cite{test2}.
        %\clearpage
        \putbib[englishsummary]
    \end{bibunit}
    % END OF English SUMMARY

    % Danish summary
    \begin{bibunit}[plainnat]
        \chapter*[Danish summary]{Danish summary}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Danish summary}
        \selectlanguage{Danish}
        \frenchspacing

        some danish text \citep{test1d} and \cite{test2d}.

        \putbib[danishsummary]
    \end{bibunit}
\end{document}
```

As far as I can see on my system the citations are correct. I added the `filecontents` package and switched to the starred version of that env, then the two bibfiles will be changed on disk if we alter them in the text file.

---

Too long for a comment, here is a super small MWE of memoir working with `bibunits`

Remember to run bibtex on all `buX.aux` (I use the `latexmk` tool, it will automatically detect the `buX.aux` files and run `bibtex` on them

So what exactly is the problem on your document?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\begin{filecontents}{mytest.bib}
@Article{test1,
  author =   {Test Testesen},
  title =    {Test},
  journal =      {Test journal},
  year =     {2018},
}
@Article{test2,
  author =   {Test T. Test},
  title =    {TestB},
  journal =      {Journal of testing},
  year =     {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[danish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\usepackage[authoryear,sectionbib,longnamesfirst]{natbib}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*


%English summary
\begin{bibunit}[plainnat]
\chapter*[Summary]{Summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary}

some text

\cite{test1}

\putbib[mytest]
\end{bibunit}

% Danish summary
\begin{bibunit}[plainnat]
\chapter*[Danish summary]{Danish summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Danish summary}
\selectlanguage{danish}
\frenchspacing

some text

\cite{test2}

\putbib[mytest]
\end{bibunit}

\end{document}
```